# Sort nomenclature according to description, rather than symbol, whilst using subgroups

Tags: sorting, nomenclature

I would like to know how to sort a nomenclature according to the description, and not the symbol, whilst still making use of subgroups (e.g. separate groups for subscripts, superscripts etc)? The following, suggested defining a new command `\Nomenclature` for sorting according to the description rather than symbol:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\newcommand\Nomenclature[2]{\nomenclature[#2]{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
Text% to produce a non-empty page

\Nomenclature{$\omega$}{Absolute Frequency}
\Nomenclature{HOA}{Acetic acid}
\Nomenclature{Al}{Aluminium}
\Nomenclature{ASTM}{American Standard Testing Machine}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

However, I am not sure how to get this to work with subgroups, which I have created using the `\nomgroup` command in the following way:

```
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Acronyms}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{R}{Roman Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{G}{Greek Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{S}{Superscripts}{% 
  \ifstrequal{#1}{U}{Subscripts}{%   
  \ifstrequal{#1}{X}{Other Symbols}{}}}}}}]
  \insertnomheaders
  }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, but you have to declare your `\Nomenclature` command to have three argument:

```
\newcommand\Nomenclature[3][X]{\nomenclature[#1#3]{#2}{#3}}
```

Also the command `\insertnomheaders` is undefined. I've redefined `\nomgroup` without it (and changed a little):

```
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Acronyms}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{R}{Roman Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{G}{Greek Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{M}{Molecules}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{X}{Other Symbols}{}}}}}]%
  }
```

When you use `\Nomenclature` you have to specify the first optional argument to be one of the ones listed in `\nomgroup` so to be inserted in the right subgroup. If you omit the optional argument the default is `X`.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\newcommand\Nomenclature[3][X]{\nomenclature[#1#3]{#2}{#3}}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Acronyms}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{R}{Roman Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{G}{Greek Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{M}{Molecules}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{X}{Other Symbols}{}}}}}]%
  }

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
Text% to produce a non-empty page

\Nomenclature[G]{$\omega$}{Absolute Frequency}
\Nomenclature[G]{$f$}{Frequency}
\Nomenclature[M]{HOA}{Acetic acid}
\Nomenclature[M]{Al}{Aluminium}
\Nomenclature[A]{ASTM}{American Standard Testing Machine}
\Nomenclature[X]{foo2}{foo2}
\Nomenclature{foo1}{foo1}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the elements are placed in the right subgroup and ordered according to their description.

Comment: Well, `f` is not really a greek symbol...